# Count sum of a subset of an array without bruteforcing it

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'll start by explaining step by step what I have to do. First I make an array containing N prime numbers that I create like this:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    if(n <= 1) return false;
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        if(n % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int p[n + d], j = 0;
for(int i = 0; j < n + d; i++) {
    if(isPrime(i)) {
            p[j] = i;
            j++;
    }
}
```

I then create a target array Q that I'm going to be using for the calculations:

```
int q[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    q[i] = p[i] * p[i + d];
}
```

Now that I have the traget array Q[N] I need to count how many times this equation is true `A + B + C + D = E`, where `{A, B, C, D, E}` are items from the array Q and `A <= B <= C <= D`. I tried this solution, but it's bruteforcing it and for bigger numbers it just takes minutes to calculate, which is not what I want.

```
int amount = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        for(int k = j; k >= 0; k--) {
            for(int l = k; l >= 0; l--) {
                for(int m = l; m >= 0; m--) {
                    if(q[j] + q[k] + q[l] + q[m] == q[i])
                        amount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << amount << endl;
```

For example if I input 15 for N and 1 for D the output should be 2 because:

```
6 + 15 + 323 + 323 = 667
6 + 143 + 221 + 1147 = 1517
```

But the code has to be optimized enough to calculate fast for N and D up to 2500.

Comment: I hope I explained my problem as much I could, but if you have any additional questions please ask right away.

Comment: "*so it doesn't really work.*". Can you be more specific? Show an input, expected output, and the results you actually get. Also, it's nice to see a [mre]. That makes it easier for us to test the program, and help you out.

Comment: For example if I input 15 for N and 1 for D the output should be 2 because:
    6 + 15 + 323 + 323 = 667
    6 + 143 + 221 + 1147 = 1517
But my approach returns 0, because it checks sums like these:
    6 + 6 + 221 + 437 = 670 (so not 667, because it chose wrong items to sum up)
    6 + 35 + 323 + 1147 = 1511 (instead of 1517 because it chose wrong items again)

Comment: Thanks, but you should add that info to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: I'll do that right now, sorry for all those mistakes but I'm a new user.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've updated the question, my solution doesn't consider all possible combinations of items and in return gives incorrect results. Could you suggest how I might loop through all possible combinations of 4 items lower than Q[I] to check if the sum of those items will equal to Q[I]?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've updated the question with a working solution, but it's bruteforcing and it works incredibly slow for higher numbers. Could you help me make it more optimized?

Comment: The question reads like it's from some contest/competitive coding/hacking site. Is it? If your goal is to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program runs slow and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is, I'm not trying to learn C++, my goal here is to learn the pattern to somehow optimize / solve this problem. I'm pretty sure I won't find the answer to this in a textbook, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Oh, but you ***do*** need to learn C++ in order to do this. If the goal is to get the sum of `E`, and the 1st value in the array is `x`, then the solution includes `x` plus whatever from the rest of the array adds up to `E-x`, or `E` withour `x`. That's a recursive algorithm. This sets the upper limit of the complexity, for all of this to O^2, instead of O^5, three orders of magnitude faster than five nested for-loops. But to correctly implement it, you ***do*** need to learn C++ to 1) implement recursion correctly, 2) know how to use containers to keep track of all `x`s, on each step.

Comment: Smallest solution is 2,2,2,7,13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To optimize this you have to invest your mathematical knowledge.

You should start from calculating prime using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or some better algorithm.

Then note that all your `q` but first must be odd. All primes except `2` are odd and all their multiplication is odd too. As a result only first item in `q` is even.

Why this is important? Your sum has even number of elements, so to be able to have odd outcome which could match `E` in `q`, `A` must be equal to first element of `q` since it only even value in `q`.

So you have only 3 free parameters: `B`, `C` and `D` and `E` can be calculated and check if it exists.

You can iterate over `B`, `C`, `D` and then binary search for `E` in `q`. This will gives algorithm with complexity `O(n^3 log n)` which is great comparing to your `O(n^5)`.

You can use `unordered_set` to match `E` in `O(1)` time instead of `O(log n)` time. So final algorithm easily ca be `O(n^3)`.

I'm quite sure you can find this kind tricks more effectively. Possibly knowledge of `d` value could be used in some way to avoid some iterations.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to implement your suggestions into my code. From what I've checked using my bruteforce solution, value of d cannot really be used in any way, except if it's 0 then there are no sums in the given range.

Comment: Is using member function find() the way to check if element is in the unordered_set you mentioned?

Comment: or [count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count) which is more handy.

Answer (score 1):

I have one trick to improve @MarekR's answer from time `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2 log(n))`.  (Unfortunately it also needs `O(n^2)` memory.)

As noted, `A` has to be the first element.  So we just have to find the other four elements.

Now here is the trick.  Generate one array of tuples `(B+C, B, C)` with `B < C`.  And another array of tuples `(E-D, E, D)` with `D < E`.  Sort both arrays.  Now walk them in parallel, looking to match up cases where `A + B+C = E-D`.  Filter out the cases where `D <= C` and voila!

Generating the arrays is `O(n^2)`.  Sorting them is `O(n^2 * log(n))`.  Walking them in parallel and grouping by value is `O(n^2)`.  Processing a group of matches with `m1` entries in the first array and `m2` in the second is `O(m1 * m2)`.  You are generating extra matches per answer, but given how few answers there are, I believe that this is negligible.  Which makes it `O(n^2 log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code can do better than O(n^3)**

Use math knowledge.

For `A+B+C+D=E` as prime to be true, consider the case where `A+B+C+D` are all odd.  In that case, the sum `E` of 4 odd numbers is an even.   Since the only even prime is 2 and sum of 4 odd primes is more than 2, `A,B,C,D` can not be all odds.  Thus `A==2`.

1. Form an array `BC` containing all combinations of [0...N)[B..N) and 3 items: B, C, Sum B+C.  Sort by the Sum.  O(N * N * log(N)).  I suspect the sorted list can be formed perhaps even closer to O(N * N), given the initial list of primes is itself ordered.  Hmmm.
2. Form an array `DE` in similar fashion with the difference of `E-D`.
3. Walk array `BC` and then walk `DE` in the reverse direction looking for `A+B+C+D=E`.

Estimate O(N * N)* log(N)) after prime table made.

---

For prime, use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: You have to do step 3 for `N` values of `E`.  Which makes this `O(N^3)`.

Comment: @btilly Hmm  I thought E was constant.  Will review.